# PHP Call outside class function inside anonymous function

Tags: php

hey guys i wanna call my function inside class A than call it inside class B within anonymous function how to do that ? here my sample code.

```
<?php

     class A extends Z{
        public function sampleFunction($post){
           // code here
        }

     }

     class B extends A{
       public __construct(){
         $this->anotherClass();
       }
    // add_action() and update_meta_box() is function from wordpress

       public function anotherClass(){
         $post = $_POST['test'];
         add_action('save_post',function($id){
           if(isset($post)){
    // here i dont know how to call it inside anonymous function
             $this->sampleFunction($post); 
             update_meta_box(
               $id,
               'key',
               strip_tags($post)
             );
           }
         });
       }

     }

    ?>
```

Comment: Solved [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20437747/php-call-outside-class-function-inside-anonymous-function)

Comment: Please do not duplicate questions across the network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify which variables you want your closure to have access to, using the `use` part of the closure -- see [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php).

```
add_action('save_post', function($id) use ($this, $post) {
    // ....
});
```